# Is this a proper way to cancel an onMouseOver which uses setTimeout? (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom, properties

I've got a working solution for an `onMouseOver` event which rolls over a set of images and replaces them in the element. Due to my lack of knowledge in JS I would like to know if this is a proper solution. It works in Chrome and Firefox.

The solution sets attributes (i.e. `isRunning="true"`, `isCanceled="true"`) , reads them depending on the user action (`onMouseOver`, `onMouseOut`) and determines if the action should be continued.

Contraint: The solution must stay in Vanilla JS. No libraries may be used.

Thanks for any suggestion!

```js
var thumbNails = {
  123: [
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188235.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188236.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188237.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188238.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188239.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188240.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188241.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188242.svg"
  ]
};

function rollover(element) {
  var id = element.getAttribute("id");
  if (!isRunning(element)) {
    setRunning(element, "true");
    setImageSrc(element, thumbNails[id][0]);
    start(1, thumbNails[id], element);
  }
}

function start(startIndex, thumbNails, element) {
  if (!isCanceled(element) && startIndex < thumbNails.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!isCanceled(element)) {
        setImageSrc(element, thumbNails[startIndex]);
      }
      startIndex++;
      console.log("currentIndex: " + startIndex + " - Running? " + isRunning(element) + " - Cancel? " + isCanceled(element));
      start(startIndex, thumbNails, element);
    }, 700);
  } else {
    setRunning(element, "false");
    setCanceled(element, "false");
  }
}

function cancel(element) {
  console.log("cancel");
  if (isRunning(element)) {
    setCanceled(element, "true");
  }
}


// HELPERS

function isRunning(element) {
  return element.getAttribute("isrunning") === "true";
}

function setRunning(element, state) {
  element.setAttribute("isrunning", state);
}

function isCanceled(element) {
  return element.getAttribute("iscanceled") === "true";
}

function setCanceled(element, state) {
  element.setAttribute("iscanceled", state);
}

function setImageSrc(element, url) {
  element.setAttribute("src", url);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="123" onmouseover="rollover(this)" onmouseout="cancel(this)" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188238.svg" width="100" height="100">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Response to your prompt

> **Due to my lack of knowledge in JS I would like to know if this is a proper solution.**

This code sets attributes on the elements to store properties. While this works, it technically leads to invalid HTML<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041243/1575353)</sup>. Alternatives include using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and setting properties on the variable representing the element. See responses to [*Custom attributes - Yea or nay?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/992115/1575353) and  [*Associate Data With HTML Element (without jQuery)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28650570/1575353)

### Other review feedback

Many developers believe it is good to move all JavaScript code out of the markup. So instead of the `onmouseover=...` and `onmouseout=...` attributes, you could register those event handlers in the JavaScript using [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var image = document.getElementById('123');
  image.addEventListener('mouseover', rollover);
  image.addEventListener('mouseout', cancel);
});
```

With an approach like this, the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword inside the functions `rollover` and `cancel` refers to the element, so there isn't a need to accept the element as a parameter. If you did want to pass parameters to those functions, it could be achieved using [partially applied-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) with [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
  //set context of 'this' to the image and pass string literal '123' as the first parameter
  image.addEventListener('mouseover', rollover.bind(image, '123'));
```

---

The **[`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)** attribute can be used instead of `.getAttribute('id')`.

So instead of this line:

> ```
> var id = element.getAttribute("id");
> ```

the same can easily be achieved with:

```
var id = element.id;
```

This may make assigning that value to a new variable superfluous.

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041243/1575353</sub>